# Change filename of upload on Form based on Unique ID on response sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an expense form where files of the invoices uploaded would be automatically changed to a Unique ID on the response spreadsheet. The Unique ID cell is auto generated based on a formula in the response sheet. This is how my sheet looks -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Eok.png)

I would the files to be renamed to the cell values in Column A.

Is there a script that can get this done?

PS - I am already using a script to automatically change the format of a new form entry on the response sheet that uses the onFormsubmit trigger. Below is the script - adding it here as I do not want the new script to not work because the trigger might be the same.

**EDIT**

Adding the link of the sheet i am using here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mbtWlKi2rOHeZCr-lQ1XrC1Z-yLv7-5XPc5OSMNO_Zg/edit#gid=1082243920&fvid=157641863

Also sharing a screenshot of what I would the final deliverable would be - [image: Sample]

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

const createTrigger = () => {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach((trigger) => {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('formRowOnFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const formRowOnFormSubmit = (e) => {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run this function manually!');
  }
  const { range } = e;
  const row = range.getRowIndex();
  if (row > 2) {
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    // Select the previous row range
    const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(`${row - 1}:${row - 1}`);
    // Get the recently added row
    const targetRange = sheet.getRange(`${row}:${row}`);
    // Copy the format only from the previous row to the current row
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When Google Form is submitted, you want to change the filename of the uploaded file from Google Form to the value of the column of the unique IDs.
- From your showing image of the Spreadsheet, the URL like `https://drive.google.com/open?id={fileId}` of the uploaded file is put into some column.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script.

Unfortunately, from your showing image of the Spreadsheet, I couldn't confirm the column letters of the columns of unique IDs and the file URLs. So, in this sample, I prepared `columnNumberOfUniqueID`. So, before you use this script, please set `columnNumberOfUniqueID` to your situation.

And, please remove the OnSubmit trigger to the function `formRowOnFormSubmit` and install the OnSubmit trigger to the same function again. By this, a new scope is added. When you don't do this, the script is not correctly run. Please be careful about this. If your actual script has already used a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, this process can be skipped.

```js
const formRowOnFormSubmit = (e) => {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run this function manually!');
  }
  const { range } = e;
  const row = range.rowStart;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (row > 2) {
    // Select the previous row range
    const sourceRange = sheet.getRange(`${row - 1}:${row - 1}`);
    // Get the recently added row
    const targetRange = sheet.getRange(`${row}:${row}`);
    // Copy the format only from the previous row to the current row
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  }


  const columnNumberOfUniqueID = 2; // Please set the column number of your unique ID. For example, 2 is column "B".

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I'm not sure whether this line is required to be used.
  e.values.forEach(v => {
    if (/^https:\/\/drive.google.com\/open\?id\=/.test(v)) {
      const fileId = v.split("=")[1].trim();
      DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setName(sheet.getRange(row, columnNumberOfUniqueID).getDisplayValue());
    }
  });
};
```

- When I tested this script using a simple sample Google Form, I confirmed that the filename of the uploaded file was changed to the column of `columnNumberOfUniqueID`.
- If this modified script cannot be used in your actual Spreadsheet, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for this - I have updated my question and shared a link of the file for reference. I have also shared a screenshot showing what I would finally like. To clarify, I would like the file uploaded through the form to be renamed to the Unique ID mentioned in Column A of the form response sheet.

Comment: @Ankur Mathur Thank you for replying. First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Hi Tanaike, thanks for this - I have updated my question and shared a link of the file for reference. I have also shared a screenshot showing what I would finally like. To clarify, I would like the file uploaded through the form to be renamed to the Unique ID mentioned in Column A of the form response sheet.`, I couldn't understand whether my proposed script worked in your situation. I apologize for this again.

Comment: @Ankur Mathur I think that from your updated question, when you modify `const columnNumberOfUniqueID = 2;` to `const columnNumberOfUniqueID = 1;`, my proposed script might be able to be used. How about this? If my proposed script was not useful, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide detailed information about your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi, I have added your script and updated the same with the sheet I have shared. It is unfortunately not giving the desired result. It would be great if you can see the sheet I have attached and the code with it.

Comment: @Ankur Mathur Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your provided Spreadsheet, there are 2 sheets. From your question, when Google Form is submitted, the submitted value is appended to the sheet `Petty Cash Payments`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, when Google Form is submitted and the function `formRowOnFormSubmit` of my propsoed script is run by `const columnNumberOfUniqueID = 1;`, I think that your goal can be achieved. How about this?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, yes it worked thank you very much!!! Sorry I had not removed the onSubmit trigger. It works after removing that. This is perfect!

Comment: @Ankur Mathur Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace the timestamp in the current line before  you run the code with an appropriate unique id that ends in a number.

```
const formRowOnFormSubmit = (e) => {
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    const cObj = { "Corporate Card": "CC", "Petty Cash": "PC" };
    const sh = e.range.getSheet();
    const srg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart - 1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
    const trg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
    srg.copyTo(trg, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
    let s = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart - 1, 1).getDisplayValue().split("-")[2];
    let n = parseInt(s) + 1;
    //Logger.log('s: %s n: %s', s, n);
    let a = `EX-${cObj[e.values[6]]}-0${n}`;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue(a);
  }
}
```

I modified one of my spreadsheets to test the timestamp replacement:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 127 | EX-PC-01 | 1 |  |  |  |  | Petty Cash |
| 128 | EX-CC-02 | 1 |  |  |  |  | Corporate Card |
| 129 | EX-PC-03 | 1 |  |  |  |  | Petty Cash |
| 130 | EX-CC-04 | 1 |  |  |  |  | Corporate Card |
| 131 | EX-PC-05 | 1 |  |  |  |  | Petty Cash |

Note: I did not test all of your code because I don't have any of your data and I don't know what you are doing with the format.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question to add the sheet and a screenshot for reference. I would like the file uploaded through the form to be renamed to the Unique ID in the Column A of the form response sheet. Thanks for your help